# Lubuntu 18.10 on NUC6CAYH as kiosk app forced shutdown every day is it okay?

Tags: linux, hardware, intel, lubuntu, kiosk

im not sure this a the right place to ask but i'll try from here

So, i am using Lubuntu 18.10 for my Kiosk App on Intel NUC6CAYH, usually the app is running 24/7..but some request came for an event that the machine can only be powered on in 09:00 - 22:00.

Because i am not stand by at the event, the machine need to be shutdown by a staff over there. My question, is it okay for intel nuc6cayh to be forced shutdown everyday?

Comment: forced shutdowns are bad, and will almost certainly result in file-system corruption eventually.   Set up a cron job to shutdown or hibernate the machine at approx 21:59.  And use wake-on-lan or a timer in your BIOS to start it up again at 09:00 (not all BIOSes support this, but many modern ones do).

Comment: yeah i think thats the best solution there is...thanks

Comment: another alternative is to plug it into a UPS (preferably installed in the kiosk's "case") that will keep the kiosk up for at least 11 hours.   as a bonus, the constant beeping may discourage whoever turns it off at the wall from doing that.   NOTE: I'm not saying that this is a **good** option (it probably isn't).